# DoubleAnimation using VisualTreeHelper works only once

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

Some code to see what's going on:

XAML file:

```
<!-- put this code into your page xaml code-->

<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Name="opabuttonstyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource BackgroundGradient-Blue}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button
            x:Name="testingIsTheFutureButton"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Click="testingIsTheFutureButton_Click"
            Content="Opacity Animation"
            Style="{StaticResource opabuttonstyle}" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackingStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="Element" />
            <TextBlock Text="Element" />
            <TextBlock Text="Element" />
            <TextBlock Text="Element" />
            <TextBlock Text="Element" />
            <TextBlock Text="Element" />
            <TextBlock Text="Element" />
            <TextBlock Text="Element" />
            <TextBlock Text="Element" />
            <TextBlock Text="Element" />
            <TextBlock Text="Element" />
            <TextBlock Text="Element" />
            <TextBlock Text="Element" />
            <TextBlock Text="Element" />
            <TextBlock Text="Element" />
            <TextBlock Text="Element" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Class file SingleAnimations.cs:

```
// This function takes UIElement and DoubleAnimate it to fade in.
public static void SimpleElementFadeIn(object sender, int fadeTime, int delay)
{
        UIElement element = sender as UIElement;    //bierz element
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        doubleAnimation.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, delay);
        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, fadeTime));
        doubleAnimation.From = 0;
        doubleAnimation.To = 1;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, element);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, "Opacity");
        storyboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
        storyboard.Begin();
}
```

Class file CollectionAnimations.cs:

```
// This function goes through every children element in UIElement (grid, 
//stackpanel or whatever we send there) and animates it using previous function
public static void OpacityWithChildren_Light(object sender, int delay)
{
    SetOpacityToZero_Deep(sender);  // set opacity to 0 to all elements before animation
    UIElement rootElement = sender as UIElement;   
    int childCount= VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(rootElement);
    if (childCount > 0)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < childCount; index++)
        {
                UIElement element = (UIElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rootElement, index);
                SingleAnimations.SimpleElementFadeIn(element, 100, delay * index);
        }
    }
}

// This function goes through every children element like the funtion above
// and sets opacity of these elements to 0 (so every element is invisible before it's animated)
public static void SetOpacityToZero_Deep(object sender)
{
    UIElement rootElement = sender as UIElement;
    int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(rootElement);
    if (childNumber > 0)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < childNumber; index++)
        {
            UIElement element = (UIElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rootElement, index);
                element.Opacity = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

To start the animation I call

```
CollectionAnimations.OpacityWithChildren_Light(stackingStackPanel, 50);
```

in the *button_click* event.

What I expect is that all of the *TextBlocks* in the *StackPanel* disappear and are going to fade in one by one. This is happening but only with first use. If I click the button again, then all of them are visible and are animated one by one - not what I want to happen. If I go back to *MainPage* and enter the page again, it will work again (once) like before.

I should clean some sort of cashe maybe. I didn't come across anything like that in the documentation or I just missed it. Nothing like that has been mentioned for independent animations. I messed with this code trying different things and approaches but nothing worked out.

Comment: This is just a comment, why not move the `element.Opacity = 0;` to foreach loop of `OpacityWithChildren_Light`?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen UIElement would be instantly animated and I want all of them to be invisible and then show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you should be able to use two Storyboards to do that, one to set the `Opacity` to 0 and the other one to play the `DoubleAnimation` as you want.

So we do not need to set the `Opacity` to 0 by `UIElement.Opacity`. When the `Storyboard` of set `Opacity` to zero is complete, we should be able to begin the `Storyboard` of fade in.

For example:

The SingleAnimation class:

```cs
internal class SingleAnimations
{
    public static DoubleAnimation SetToZero(object sender)
    {
        var element = sender as UIElement;
        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        doubleAnimation.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
        doubleAnimation.From = 1;
        doubleAnimation.To = 0;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, element);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, "Opacity");
        return doubleAnimation;

    }

    public static DoubleAnimation SimpleElementFadeIn(object sender, int fadeTime, int delay)
    {
        var element = sender as UIElement;
        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        doubleAnimation.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, delay);
        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, fadeTime));
        doubleAnimation.From = 0;
        doubleAnimation.To = 1;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, element);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, "Opacity");
        return doubleAnimation;

    }
```

The OpacityWithChildren_Light method:

```cs
public static  void OpacityWithChildren_Light(object sender, int delay)
{
    var storyboardOfSetOpacityToZero = new Storyboard();
    var storyboardFadeIn = new Storyboard();
    UIElement rootElement = sender as UIElement;
    int childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(rootElement);
    if (childCount > 0)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < childCount; index++)
        {
            UIElement element = (UIElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rootElement, index);
            var SetOpacityToZero = SingleAnimations.SetToZero(element);
            var SetOpacityToOne = SingleAnimations.SimpleElementFadeIn(element, 100, delay * index);
            storyboardOfSetOpacityToZero.Children.Add(SetOpacityToZero);
            storyboardFadeIn.Children.Add(SetOpacityToOne);
        }
        storyboardOfSetOpacityToZero.Begin();
        storyboardOfSetOpacityToZero.Completed += (s, e) => { storyboardFadeIn.Begin(); };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This code is way better than mine and also works like a charm :) Still it's interesting why Opacity has to be animated to be set to 0 and doesn't work other way.